# OpenSSL file based pseudo-engine

Tags: cryptography, openssl, hsm

Are there any OpenSSL engines that do everything in software and store the secret keys in a file (possibly even in plaintext)?

Perhaps this can somehow be achieved with OpenSSL alone?

The purpose of this is to test whether a piece of software interfaces correctly with the engine API, without having any hardware.

It is assumed that at a later point in time, when an HSM is acquired - it would work with the software right away (provided that the HSM vendor offers an OpenSSL engine).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether pure software implementation of OpenSSL engine exists but you could try [engine_pkcs11](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Engine-pkcs11-quickstart) with [SoftHSM](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv1).